# Is there any Mobile app Security Testing tool which uses a server-agent configuration instead of using proxy for intercepting requests?

Tags: security-testing, zapproxy, mobile-applications

I want to perform the security testing of a mobile app. I am using ZAP for Testing Web application. For testing web application, we no longer need to use a proxy, but for mobile application, proxy setup is needed. Since my Desktop doesn't have WIFI support, on which I am running ZAP. 
Is there any other way I can test mobile application on ZAP or any other application using a client-server tool which does not need proxy??